# SQL Server Debugger showing wrong line no

Tags: sql-server

I am working on `SQL Stored Procedure` in SQL Server Management Studio. When I `debug` my `SQL` it is showing incorrect line number as

> Error in Line 261 & 263

```
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 261
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'LEFT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 263
Incorrect syntax near '0'.
```

But the total number of lines is only 185. How can I find the actual line of error?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable line number in `SSMS` to show the line number as shown below. It will give the actual line indication. This issue might be due to blank lines. You can also delete that blank lines.

> Tools - Options - Text Editor - Transact-SQL - Line Numbers

To enable line number follow the above steps. You can get help from [**here**](https://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/Display-Line-Numbers-In-SSMS-SQL-Server-Management-Studio/)